# React Navigation : How to trigger transition animation with StackActions.reset?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm a beginner with react navigation. 
I would like to trigger transition animation with "StackActions.reset".

should you add an action?

Here is my code:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: As you can see in this topic this is a real problem with React-navigation. Their concept is "there cannot be a transition if there is no index". If you want to use it for your splash screen, one solution is to keep the splash in the stack (and handle consequents problems for this, like impeach the possibility of going back to this screen). Anyway, have a good read: https://github.com/react-navigation/stack/issues/139